# SQL Query to find out total duration spent by a user

Tags: sql, optimization, google-bigquery

I have a table similar to the one below:

[image]

What's the best way to find the total duration spent by users like below?

[image]

I used the below query. Somehow I am feeling there will be a better way to this:

```
SELECT USER_NAME, SUM(SESSION_DURATION) AS TOTAL_DURATION FROM (
  SELECT LOGIN.USER_NAME, LOGIN.APP_SESSION, (LOGOUT.TIME-LOGIN.TIME) AS SESSION_DURATION 
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `***.USER_APP_TEST`
    WHERE STATE = 'LOGIN'
  ) AS LOGIN 

  JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM  `***.USER_APP_TEST`
    WHERE STATE = 'LOGOUT'
  ) AS LOGOUT

  ON LOGIN.USER_NAME = LOGOUT.USER_NAME
  AND LOGIN.APP_SESSION = LOGOUT.APP_SESSION
)
GROUP BY USER_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below query not using join operation as well.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'U1' user_name, 'S1' app_session, 'LOGIN' state, 10 time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2', 'S1', 'LOGIN',  10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2', 'S1', 'LOGOUT',  11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1', 'S1', 'LOGOUT',  12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1', 'S2', 'LOGIN',  14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1', 'S2', 'LOGOUT',  16
)
-- query starts here
SELECT DISTINCT user_name, SUM(MAX(time) - MIN(time)) OVER w AS total_duration
  FROM sample_table WHERE state IN ('LOGIN', 'LOGOUT')
 GROUP BY user_name, app_session
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_name);

-- query result
+-----------+----------------+
| user_name | total_duration |
+-----------+----------------+
| U1        |              4 |
| U2        |              1 |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the WINDOW works here ?

Comment: `WINDOW` clause is used when you define a named window frame. You can 
 define `SUM(MAX(time) - MIN(time)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_name)` as well in this case.   `WINDOW` clause is mostly useful for repetitive uses of same window frame in a single *select* statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks valid and reasonable.

An alternative might be to use a self-join on the table to match each LOGIN event with the corresponding LOGOUT event.

```
SELECT 
  t1.USER_NAME, 
  SUM(t2.TIME - t1.TIME) AS TOTAL_DURATION 
FROM `***.USER_APP_TEST` t1 
JOIN `***.USER_APP_TEST` t2 
  ON t1.USER_NAME = t2.USER_NAME 
  AND t1.APP_SESSION = t2.APP_SESSION 
  AND t1.STATE = 'LOGIN' 
  AND t2.STATE = 'LOGOUT' 
  AND t1.TIME < t2.TIME 
GROUP BY t1.USER_NAME
```

- `t1` and `t2` are aliases for the same table
- `t1.TIME < t2.TIME` ensures that only matching `LOGOUT` events that occur after the corresponding `LOGIN` event are included.

Comment: you need to group by session too